# MultiSelect Dropdwon list value Move To Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this javascript code for copying a field value to another field. When we just like use check box in dropdown, we have to click a check box then value copy into a text-box.

But it selects only single not multiple value in text box...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dropdown").on('change',function(){
            var dropdownVal=this.value;

            $("#textbox").val(dropdownVal); 
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
    <p>
        <select multiple="multiple" name="dropdown"  id="dropdown" style="width:370px">
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <input type="text" class="normal" id="textbox" name="textbox"  style="width:450px;"></td>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select").multiselect().multiselectfilter();
</script>
```

I am using multiple select drop-down list with check-box.

Comment: Could you put your code (including html) in a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Check It Now I have including html part ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Q552/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.value;` should be `$(this).val();` if you are using Jquery. and you needed `click` event instead of `change` event. see this working version: http://jsfiddle.net/5Q552/1/

and just as info: instead of `$(document).ready(function(){});`
you can also use: `$(function(){});`

```
$(function() {
  $("#dropdown").on('click',function(){
    var dropdownVal=$(this).val();
    $("#textbox").val(dropdownVal);         
  });
});

<form>
 <p>
 <select multiple="multiple" name="dropdown"  id="dropdown" style="width:370px">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>        
 </select>
 </p>
 <input type="text" class="normal" id="textbox" name="textbox" style="width:450px;"></td>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks doniyor can you check It only Select Single value ...I need multple value.. with , like red,green

Comment: @user3503395 you can check multiple value with ctrl, right?

Comment: ok fine now it  work....but when i am Use this code  <script type="text/javascript">
//$("select").multiselect().multiselectfilter();
</script>
it not work plz check ,,,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893384/how-to-value-copy-and-paste-in-another-textbox-from-dropdown

Comment: plz check this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893384/how-to-value-copy-and-paste-in-another-textbox-from-dropdown